# "Was ist der Preis" - "Preis" in this instance Akkusativ or Dativ?

Tags: english-to-german

der - it is the article is feminine Akkusativ or Dativ. In this instance Akkusativ or Dativ?

Comment: https://www.verbformen.de/deklination/substantive/Preis.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preis is a masculine noun. So here the case is actually nominative.

Comment: Even if it were feminine, without context it would be impossible to tell whether it's datie or genitive.